# phonegap buttons not showing after pressed

Tags: cordova, dreamweaver

Building an app and afer build the pressed button is showing a strange transparency. Not always, but is pretty annoying when it does. It looks like there is a fault in the app. Is it or am I doing something wrong?

Here is a *printscreen* of the issue:

[image]